# Geckodriver selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

When executing the following script,

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Log
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager
from dotenv import load_dotenv   # for python-dotenv method


load_dotenv() 
os.environ['WDM_LOG_LEVEL'] = '0'
os.environ['WDM_PRINT_FIRST_LINE'] = 'False'
os.environ['WDM_LOG'] = str(logging.NOTSET)
os.environ['WDM_PROGRESS_BAR'] = str(0)

options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
log = Log()
log.level = "info"  # OK
# log.level = "warn"  # KO
# log.level = "error"  # OK
# log.level = "fatal"  # KO
# log.level = "debug"  # KO
# log.level = "trace"  # KO

options.add_argument(log.level)

options.add_argument('--headless')

driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install(), log_output='./Logs/geckodriver_log_output.log'),
                           options=options)
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/Capture.py", line 295, in <module>
    main(localdir, vars(args))
  File "/home/user/Capture.py", line 212, in main
    driver = webdriver.Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install(), log_output='./Logs/geckodriver_log_output.log'),
  File "/home/user/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/home/user/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/home/user/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 290, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/home/user/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 345, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/user/lib64/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Error: NS_BINDING_ABORTED
Stacktrace:
#checkLoadingState@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:209:28
onStateChange@chrome://remote/content/shared/Navigate.jsm:254:28
```

I see that adding the log.level option generates it, more or less randomly depending on the level chosen. Although the 'info' comment is OK, this is not the case on every run.

In addition, the log_output parameter is ignored and the geckodriver.log file continues to be generated in the current folder.

I'm using :

- Almalinux 9.2
- Linux 5.14.0-284.25.1.el9_2.x86_64
- firefox-102.14.0-1.el9_2.alma.x86_64 is installed
- Python 3.9

Package:

- selenium 4.11.2
- webdriver-manager 4.0.0

Can you help me solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: it seems that this error occurs the first time the command is used in a day (or period).

In fact, I run several scripts using this syntax and the error only appears the first time the command is used.